# How to bin observations over a time series in r?

Tags: r

I have an data set which looks like this:

```
  VisitID                  Start
1       0 2015-02-15 09:46:43.17
2       1 2015-02-15 09:47:37.84
3       2 2015-02-15 09:58:46.42
4       3 2015-02-15 09:58:48.46
5       4 2015-02-15 10:28:25.09
6       5 2015-02-15 10:33:43.53
```

I want to make a bar plot of count per one hour(y-axis) vs. absolute time(x-axis), meaning how many observations were in one hour.
can you please help?
Thanks,
Guy

Comment: have you looked at strsplit(as.character(temp$Start), " ") to break apart the Start values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
DF <- read.csv(text=
"VisitID,Start
0,2015-02-15 09:46:43.17
1,2015-02-15 09:47:37.84
2,2015-02-15 09:58:46.42
3,2015-02-15 09:58:48.46
4,2015-02-15 10:28:25.09
5,2015-02-15 10:33:43.53",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF$StartDate <- strptime(DF$Start, tz='GMT', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")

hours <- vapply(split(1:nrow(DF),format(DF$StartDate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00",tz='UTC')),length,0)

barplot(hours)
```

[image]

Comment: Another possible solution instead of using the format statement in above is to use cut:  barplot(tapply(DF$StartDate, cut(DF$StartDate, "hour"), FUN=length))